# Need records from one table if value matches or if value exists in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need all tasks that match 3 OR situations.

Here is the query:
UPDATE:

Tried the following:

```
SELECT TASKS.task_id, TASKS.task_title, TASKS.task_description, TASKS.task_assigned_name, TASKS.task_assigned_phone_number, TASKS.task_due_date_time, TASKS.task_category
FROM TASKS
WHERE TASKS.task_complete = 1 AND 
      (TASKS.task_creator_id = ? OR 
       TASKS.task_assigned_user_id = ? OR
       EXISTS (SELECT  WATCHERS.task_id
                     FROM WATCHERS
                     WHERE WATCHERS.task_id = TASK.task_id AND
                           WATCHERS.watcher_user_id = ?
                    )
     );
```

ALSO Tried:

```
SELECT TASKS.task_id, 
       TASKS.task_title, 
       TASKS.task_description, 
       TASKS.task_assigned_name, 
       TASKS.task_assigned_phone_number, 
       TASKS.task_due_date_time, 
       TASKS.task_category
FROM TASKS
JOIN WATCHERS on WATCHERS.task_id = TASK.task_id
WHERE TASKS.task_complete = 1 AND 
  (TASKS.task_creator_id = ? OR 
   TASKS.task_assigned_user_id = ? OR
   WATCHERS.watcher_user_id = ?);
```

This is the tables example for user_id 8:

```
TASK
{task_id: 1, task_complete: 1, task_creator_id: 8, task_assigned_user_id:null}
{task_id: 2, task_complete: 1, task_creator_id: 4, task_assigned_user_id:null}
{task_id: 3, task_complete: 1, task_creator_id: 4, task_assigned_user_id:8}
{task_id: 4, task_complete: 1, task_creator_id: 4, task_assigned_user_id:2}

Watcher:
{task_id: 1, watcher_user_id :7}
{task_id: 2, watcher_user_id :8}

Expected Results:
{task_id: 1, task_complete: 1, task_creator_id: 8, task_assigned_user_id:null}
{task_id: 2, task_complete: 1, task_creator_id: 4, task_assigned_user_id:null}
{task_id: 3, task_complete: 1, task_creator_id: 4, task_assigned_user_id:8}
```

Comment: Remove WHERE before EXISTS

Comment: Please see update @forpas I tried that and another query